# Unable to get program to use user input

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that's supposed to simulate craps and after, as far as I know, making no major changes, the program appears to have stopped using the user input that I give it. Any idea why?

UPDATE: the error only happens when the dice roll does not equal 7 or 11.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Craps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bet=0;
    int availableMoney=1000;
    Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in);
    int diceValue=0;
    int die1=0;
    int die2=0;
    int numberTryingFor=0;
    Random diceNumber=new Random();
    boolean isItTheBeginningOfTheRound=true;
    System.out.println("Welcome to craps!");
    System.out.println("You have "+availableMoney+" dollars available.");
    while(availableMoney>0){
        //sets up round
        System.out.println("Please input a bet.");
        bet=userInput.nextInt();
        die1=1+diceNumber.nextInt(6);
        die2=1+diceNumber.nextInt(6);
        diceValue=die1+die2;
        /*System.out.println(die1);
        System.out.println(die2);
        System.out.println(diceValue);
        System.out.println(availableMoney);*/
        if(diceValue==7||diceValue==11&&isItTheBeginningOfTheRound){
            availableMoney=availableMoney+bet;
            System.out.println("Your roll is "+diceValue);
            System.out.println("You win! You now have "+availableMoney+" dollars available.");
        }else if(diceValue==2||diceValue==3||diceValue==12&&isItTheBeginningOfTheRound){
            availableMoney=availableMoney-bet;
            System.out.println("Your roll is "+diceValue);
            System.out.println("You lost. You now have "+availableMoney+" dollars available.");
        }else{
            diceValue = tryForPoint(diceValue, numberTryingFor, diceNumber);
            if(diceValue==7&&!isItTheBeginningOfTheRound){
                availableMoney=availableMoney-bet;
                System.out.println("Your roll is "+diceValue);
                System.out.println("Uh Oh! You lost. You now have "+availableMoney+"left.");
            }else{
                availableMoney=availableMoney+bet;
                System.out.println("Your roll is "+diceValue);
                System.out.println("You won!You now have "+availableMoney);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("You are out of money. You lose.");
}


public static int tryForPoint(int diceValue, int numberTryingFor,
        Random diceNumber) {
    int die1;
    int die2;
    while(diceValue!=7||numberTryingFor!=diceValue){
        die1=1+diceNumber.nextInt(6);
        die2=1+diceNumber.nextInt(6);
        diceValue=die1+die2;}
    return diceValue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never change the value of isItTheBeginningOfTheRound, so the secondary block never executes because

! isItTheBeginningOfTheRound is always false.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you, I really appreciate it

Comment: @JJHersh-Accept this answer.